# type mismatch error in VBA, where is the mistake

Tags: vba

Hey I have no idea why I get an error "run time error 13 type mismatch". Thats my code and the place where I get an error:

[image]

EDIT: That  is my code:

```
Function payoff(S_T, K, CallPut As String)
If CallPut = "call" Then
    omega = 1
Else: omega = -1
End If

payoff = WorksheetFunction.Max(omega * (S_T - K), 0)

End Function

Function BS_trajektoria(S_0 As Double, T As Double, r As Double, q As Double, sigma As Double, N As Long) As Double()

Randomize
Dim S() As Double
Dim delta_t As Double
Dim i As Long
ReDim S(N)
S(0) = S_0
delta_t = T / N

For i = 1 To N
    S(i) = S(i - 1) * Exp((r - q - 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * delta_t + sigma * delta_t ^ 0.5 * Application.NormSInv(Rnd))
Next i

BS_trajektoria = S
End Function

Function barrier_MC(S_0 As Double, K As Double, T As Double, r As Double, q As Double, sigma As Double, _
                        B As Double, N As Long, num_of_sim As Long, CallPut As String, BarType As String) As Double

Randomize
Dim max_value As Double
Dim suma_wyplat As Double
Dim wyplata As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim S() As Double
suma_wyplat = 0

If (BarType = "DO" Or BarType = "DI") And B > S_0 Then
    MsgBox "Too high barrier!"
    Exit Function
ElseIf (BarType = "UO" Or BarType = "UI") And B < S_0 Then
    MsgBox "Too low barrier!"
    Exit Function
End If

With WorksheetFunction
For i = 1 To num_of_sim
    S = BS_trajektoria(S_0, T, r, q, sigma, N)
    max_value = .Max(S)
    If max_value >= B Then
        wyplata = 0
    Else
        wyplata = payoff(S(N), K, CallPut)
    End If
    suma_wyplat = suma_wyplat + wyplata
Next i
End With
barrier_MC = Exp(-r * T) * suma_wyplat / num_of_sim
End Function

Sub test3()
MsgBox barrier_MC(100, 100, 1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.2, 120, 1000, 1000000, "call", "UO")
End Sub
```

Anyone know where is the problem? For smaller value of N and num_of_sim everything works fine, the problem is when I use bigger values for these variables.

Comment: Also provide how you are calling the function (i.e. sample arguments).

Comment: There is no obvious reason that the code in the image should throw that error at that point, so I do suspect that the problem is with how you are using that function. As others have said, a [mcve] would help.

Comment: @BIgBen 
I edit my question

Comment: What is `maks`? Your code can't be run by others as is, so it isn't a [mcve]. To make such an example, check if what you post is enough to replicate the error in a new workbook. With VBA it is easy to overlook some external dependencies.

Comment: Im sorry I forget that i use my own max function. I edit the code, now should be OK

Comment: Take that line of code you highlighted, and break it into smaller pieces using separate variables.  Keep doing this until you've narrowed down the problem to a smaller, more specific expression that is trivially diagnosable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a new `Double` variable called `rand` and modify the main loop so that it looks like:

```
For i = 1 To N
    rand = Rnd
    S(i) = S(i - 1) * Exp((r - q - 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * delta_t + sigma * delta_t ^ 0.5 * Application.NormSInv(rand))
Next i
```

you will see that the problem *always* happens when `rand = 0`. Why it throws that particular error is a bit of a mystery, but it is what it is. As a fix, what you could do is to keep the code as modified above with the following twist:

```
For i = 1 To N
    rand = Rnd
    If rand = 0 Then rand = 0.0000001
    S(i) = S(i - 1) * Exp((r - q - 0.5 * sigma ^ 2) * delta_t + sigma * delta_t ^ 0.5 * Application.NormSInv(rand))
Next i
```

Then the code will run without error. It is still somewhat slow, but optimizing it (if possible) would be for a different question.

Comment: It throws the error because `Application.NormSInv(0)` returns an error value, which will blow up the multiplication.

Comment: Normsinv always throws errors if the argument is <=0 or >=1, so this is expected. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/normsinv-function-8d1bce66-8e4d-4f3b-967c-30eed61f019d

Comment: @aucuparia The question is why it throws a type-mismatch error instead of some other error. Another question is -- why is rnd = 0 even being encountered? It should be a rare situation, but OP's code triggers it all the time. Perhaps `Randomize` should be moved to the calling sub.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, and thanks for explaining the type mismatch. OP must be implicitly calling `rnd` a huge number of times. When I run `Application.NormSInv(rnd)` in a loop with a simple counter, it doesn't fail until it has run for millions of times.

Comment: Same, I eventually hit the Type Mismatch after letting Excel spin for a while.

Comment: Thanks for your help! How long did it take to compile the code?

Comment: @Kerni If by "compile" you mean "run to completion" -- I ended up killing it before then, but at least it didn't crash. [codereview.se] is another stack exchange community which is a good place to ask about improving the code. Ultimately, VBA just isn't very fast and isn't ideal for computations that takes tens of millions of steps. The blog [Newton Excel Bach](https://newtonexcelbach.com/) has some interesting articles for using Excel for serious STEM computations.